# Print and Execute formatting

Tags: sql-server, format

[image: picture of query and printout]

I have written a script that needs to be checked over before I can run it (@printonly = 0)

I need to format the script for readability first. I am wrapping the statements into a variable then printing the variable.

I want to keep the query section tidy, but also the print section outputting in a desirable format.

1) The (second) UPDATE in the print area I want a blank new line, then showing the UPDATE.
Can i build this into the query at the top?

2) The (third) UPDATE in the print area appears as tabbed across due to the clean formatting in the query area. How can I get this untabbed in the print area, while maintaining good formatting in the query area?

3) Same as number 1), I need a new blank line before the (fourth) UPDATE.

```
DECLARE @remoteinstance nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @exec nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @printonly bit
SET @printonly = 1

        --section 1
    SET @remoteinstance = '[linkedservername]'
    SET @exec = 'UPDATE r_st
                         SET.....
                         FROM.... AS st
                         INNER JOIN ' + @remoteinstance + '.. AS r_st
                         st... = r_st... AND st... <> r_st... '
    IF (@printonly = 1)  BEGIN PRINT @exec END
                    ELSE BEGIN EXEC (@exec) END

            SET @exec = 'UPDATE ' + @remoteinstance + '...
            SET xx = xy

            UPDATE ' + @remoteinstance + '....
            SET xz = xa
            WHERE ..... '

    IF (@printonly = 1)  BEGIN PRINT @exec END
                ELSE BEGIN EXEC (@exec) END

--section 2 - 
       SET @remoteinstance = '[next linkedservername]'
       SET @exec = ' {same as above}....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CHAR(9)` to control tabs and `CHAR(13)` for line breaks.

```
declare @x varchar(100) = 'A';
set @x = @x + CHAR(13) + 'B';
set @x = @x + CHAR(9) + 'C';
print @x;
```

Results:

```
A
B   C
```

If you want to replace spacing or tabs, use `REPLACE`.

```
print REPLACE(@x, CHAR(9), '!')
```

Results:

```
A
B!C
```

Comment: Are the semicolons required after the declare and set statements?

Comment: Not now but in the future they may be so best you start doing it.